# Java Dynamically creating objects

Tags: java, object, dynamic

I am currently writing a JSON parser using Java but I'm having trouble deciding which tactic I should use for this task. Note that answers on this are going to influence future tactics for me, so please try to keep your approach as generic as possible; this is just an example.

First of all we need the parser, but then I thought of the following: why not create an `enum` for the JSON -`array` and JSON - `objects`? Eventually the code will be much more object oriented and if a new type in JSON comes out (which is never going to happen probably) you have to write less code. So my `enum` would look like this:

```
public enum Brackets {
  Object( '{', '}', JSONObject.class),
  Array( '[', ']', JSONArray.class);

  public final char startChar;
  public final char endChar;
  public final Class<?> correspondingClass;
  private Brackets(char start, char end, Class<?> corresponding) {
    startChar = start;
    endChar = end;
    correspondingClass = corresponding;
  }
}
```

Through the standard enum methods one could basically iterate over the actual enumerations and take proper actions on proper situations.

To come back on the 'new JSON types,' it is imaginary. Lets say person X says, lets add '(', ')' objects which stands for Y. I want something where you can add something very easy without a hassle, with this enum I only have to add a new enumeration:

```
Y( '(', ')', JSONY.class)
```

To me it really looks hardcoded if you just use those two objects ( so it would look like:

```
public class Parser { 
   // ......
   public Object getJSON(String t) {
      if(/* .... */) {
         return new JSONObject(t);
      } else f ( /* .... */ ) {
          return new JSONArray(t);
      }
      return null;
   }
   // ......
}
```

Of course the constructors would be different and stuff, but that is not the pont), and if you do it through reflection it is only based on the enumeration and the algorithm should do the rest for you ( So this will look like:

```
public class Parser {
  //....
  public Object getJSON(String t) {
     for(Brackets b : Brackets.values()) {
        if( /* .... */ ) {
           return b.correspondingClass.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(t);
        }
     }
     return null;
  }
}
```

).

So what is a better practise, to hardcode if you know that only those two objects will be available or do it through reflection and make your life easier if a new so-called 'JSON type' comes out?

I want to emphasize that this is not about the algorithm on how to parse it properly, but more about what is better to do.

Comment: What you mean by creating new object? Please rephrase using "class" and "instance" terms, they're way easier to understand. Moreover, what you mean by new JSON type?

Comment: If you want an example of a very generic way of handling JSON you can check out Jackson. Start with `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory`. It also handles parameterized types.

Comment: What's a matter with [existing JSON parsers?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html)  Are you doing this as a exercise, or some other reason?

Comment: You could add a method `parse` to the enum that will recursively parse the remaining string starting at the current position.  This will make all type selection redundant.  This is actually a standard parser implementation technique that works with pure OO techniques and no reflection at all.

Comment: Can you maybe post an example of how that would work 5gon12eder?

Comment: I have tried to write this up as an answer but I had to give up as I saw no beginning and no end and would have ended up writing a complete parser for the answer.  If you have an academic interest in parsers, grab a book on compiler technology and look up [recursive descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser).  (Sadly, the code example on Wikipedia will not be helpful.)  If all you want is parsing some JSON string: Simply use one of the readily available free software libraries for parsing JSON in Java.  JSON is actually a classic example in teaching compilers.

Comment: @codequestioneer If you reply to someones comment, please precede the name with an `@` sign so the person will be notified.  I only discovered your reply by coincidence.

Comment: Thanks for putting so much effort for my question, I really appreciate it. Im going to do some research on recursive descent parsing, hoping I will learn more than I already know and hopefully write a proper parser for JSON. 
My goal here is with my current project to do everything from scratch, and not using libraries. You may call it reinventing the wheel, but I call it learning. You learn to code by doing it.
Thanks again @5gon12eder

Comment: Writing parsers is cool stuff and can tech you *a lot* about computer science.  Great if you have the time any energy to do it.  I hope you are not facing a deadline, though. ;-)

Comment: @5gon12eder fortunately Im not really on a deadline ;)
I also have found a really good website about [recursive descent parsers](http://www.cs.engr.uky.edu/~lewis/essays/compilers/rec-des.html)